# Openstack Glance Image Corrupted

Tags: openstack, ceph, openstack-glance, glance

I have an openstack instance up and running for 4 months and would like to migrate it to another nova node. When I click migrate instance option of that 4 month running instance on openstack dashboard. ERROR shown as the image is without associate data. Given that the new nova node has enough cpu, ram and storage.

The error message is like below:

> Image c4ef6b0a-a218-46d3-aea9-4ebc9c13f453 is unacceptable: Image has no associated data

The image is the official ubuntu 20.04 qcow image. I try to create new instance with this image but failed.

It seems that the glance image is corrupted making it failed to build instance. The instance right now is in ERROR state. Is there any way I can repair the glance image like without changing image ID and bring back my instance?

Let me know if I need to provide further information.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What exactly did you do, which commands? Can you still use the image to build new instances?

Comment: @eblock I cannot use the image to build new instances. I have an openstack instance up and running for 4 months and would like to migrate it to another nova node. When I click migrate instance option of that 4 month running instance on openstack dashboard. ERROR shown as the image is without associate data. Given that the new nova node has enough cpu, ram and storage.

Comment: Please update your question with the additional information as it can get lost in the comments. Is the tag correct and ceph is your storage backend?

Comment: Updated and yes ceph is my storage backend

Comment: Does the image exist in the ceph backend? Can you download it via `openstack image save --file <filename> <image>`?

Comment: Seems it is not in the ceph backend, Unable to download image: InvalidResponse shown when using the command you give me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132285/discussion-between-ony4869-and-eblock).