# launching first vm after openstack ansible deployment

Tags: openstack, provisioning, glance

launching my first vm after depoloying openstack ansible.

> Build of instance 7a91b5e8-23cc-4ec3-9178-aada6a302a4a aborted: Image 272e3979-c387-4651-84e5-1adcdebfa955 is unacceptable: Image has no associated data

> Traceback (most recent call last): File "/openstack/venvs/nova-25.2.0/lib/python3.10/site-packages/nova/compute/manager.py", line 2489, in _build_and_run_instance self.driver.spawn(context, instance, image_meta, File "/openstack/venvs/nova-25.2.0/lib/python3.10/site-packages/nova/virt/libvirt/driver.py", line 4306, in spawn created_instance_dir, created_disks = self._create_image( File "/openstack/venvs/nova-25.2.0/lib/python3.10/site-packages/nova/virt/libvirt/driver.py", line 4701, in _create_image created_disks = self._create_and_inject_local_root( File "/openstack/venvs/nova-25.2.0/lib/python3.10/site-packages/nova/virt/libvirt/driver.py", line 4829, in _create_and_inject_local_root self._try_fetch_image_cache(backend, fetch_func, context, File "/openstack/venvs/nova-25.2.0/lib/python3.10/site-packages/nova/virt/libvirt/driver.py", line 10621, in _try_fetch_image_cache image.cache(fetch_func=fetch_func, File "/openstack/venvs/nova-25.2.0/lib/python3.10/site-packages/nova/virt/libvirt/imagebackend.py", line 274, in cache self.create_image(fetch_func_sync, base, size, File "/openstack/venvs/nova-25.2.0/lib/python3.10/site-packages/nova/virt/libvirt/imagebackend.py", line 638, in create_image prepare_template(target=base, *args, **kwargs) File "/openstack/venvs/nova-25.2.0/lib/python3.10/site-packages/oslo_concurrency/lockutils.py", line 391, in inner return f(*args, **kwargs) File "/openstack/venvs/nova-25.2.0/lib/python3.10/site-packages/nova/virt/libvirt/imagebackend.py", line 271, in fetch_func_sync fetch_func(target=target, *args, **kwargs) File "/openstack/venvs/nova-25.2.0/lib/python3.10/site-packages/nova/virt/libvirt/utils.py", line 395, in fetch_image images.fetch_to_raw(context, image_id, target, trusted_certs) File "/openstack/venvs/nova-25.2.0/lib/python3.10/site-packages/nova/virt/images.py", line 115, in fetch_to_raw fetch(context, image_href, path_tmp, trusted_certs) File "/openstack/venvs/nova-25.2.0/lib/python3.10/site-packages/nova/virt/images.py", line 105, in fetch IMAGE_API.download(context, image_href, dest_path=path, File "/openstack/venvs/nova-25.2.0/lib/python3.10/site-packages/nova/image/glance.py", line 1298, in download return session.download(context, image_id, data=data, File "/openstack/venvs/nova-25.2.0/lib/python3.10/site-packages/nova/image/glance.py", line 384, in download raise exception.ImageUnacceptable(image_id=image_id, nova.exception.ImageUnacceptable: Image 272e3979-c387-4651-84e5-1adcdebfa955 is unacceptable: Image has no associated data During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred: Traceback (most recent call last): File "/openstack/venvs/nova-25.2.0/lib/python3.10/site-packages/nova/compute/manager.py", line 2312, in _do_build_and_run_instance self._build_and_run_instance(context, instance, image, File "/openstack/venvs/nova-25.2.0/lib/python3.10/site-packages/nova/compute/manager.py", line 2574, in _build_and_run_instance raise exception.BuildAbortException(instance_uuid=instance.uuid, nova.exception.BuildAbortException: Build of instance 7a91b5e8-23cc-4ec3-9178-aada6a302a4a aborted: Image 272e3979-c387-4651-84e5-1adcdebfa955 is unacceptable: Image has no associated data

image: cirros-0.5.1-x86_64-disk.img
flavor: m1.small (2Gb ram, 1 cpu, 30gb disk)

Comment: Depending on your storage backend this [thread](https://serverfault.com/questions/1086145/openstack-glance-image-corrupted) might help. In that case the root cause was that the image was not properly uploaded to ceph.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the issue was in /etc/neutron/plugin/ml2/ml2_conf.ini physical_interface_mappings=flat:eth12 changed to the eno4 which i am using for neutron.